# passing arguments by a button's tag in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I saw someone passing arguments by a button's tag as follow.
how could this work? and is it safe to do like this ?

```
NSCustomClass* cls = [[NSCustomClass alloc] init:@"",@"",@""];
[button setTag:(int) cls];



- (void)OnClick:(id)sender
{
    NSCustomClass* cls = (NSCustomClass*)[sender tag];
    // to do something with the "cls".
    [cls release];
}
```

In fact,I didn't get weird results.

It works fine by passing arguments like 'NSString','NSArray' in this way.

Can you tell me why it is a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you never want to abuse the frameworks. The tag is intended to store an integer and is used mainly to access a view with viewWithTag:, which can be useful in some cases if your view was built in Interface Builder but a referencing IBOutlet is inappropriate. Stuffing a pointer into an int can give unpredictable results, as others have indicated.

On top of that there's a memory management issue. Even if the pointer survives the cast you aren't retaining the object being pointed to. This in effect is a weak pointer but without any management by the run-time. Attempts to use the pointer will likely lead to the dreaded EXC_BAD_ACCESS. And who knows what ARC might do with this mess - blow up, I would expect.

To attach data to a button (which in and of itself sounds like a possible design flaw) you should either subclass or leverage the power of the run-time with objc_setAssociatedObject() and friends.

Answer (score 2):

Casting a custom class to an int is a very bad idea and you'll get weird results.

The `tag` is an integer property on all UI elements. It is declared as such on `UIView`:

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger tag;
```

You can assign any integer value to it, including any predefined constants:

```
#define Button1Constant 1
#define PushButtonConstant 2
// …Code
[button setTag:PushButtonConstant];
// …More code
if (sender.tag == PushButtonContent)
    // Handle
```

Comment: To elaborate, this works because NSInteger is the same size as a C pointer on any given platform. Bad idea anyway because if you release the object, the button tag will be a pointer to nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

In general, casting from a pointer type to an integer type usually indicates a design flaw; there are very few legitimate reasons to do this, and I would strongly discourage doing it, especially in this case. It may work, but it's not guaranteed to work, simply because the `tag` property is not documented to be used this way. The more “hacks” that you put in your code, the harder it is to maintain.

Don't learn from the code where you saw this, instead stick to reputable tutorials and books.

As a side note, it is conventional in Objective-C to name all methods starting with a lowercase letter, so the method should be `onClick:` and not `OnClick:`. The exception to this rule is when the method starts with an acronym, for example `-[NSString UTF8String]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass from UIButton and define a property by yourself, instead of using its tag property.